# How to detect if side menu is open/closed in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using `cordova-google-maps` plugin with my ionic 2 app, and I want to show the menu (sidenav) on that page. Problem is for the sidenav to receive events properly I need to call `map.setClickable( false )` while opening the sidenav and set it back to `true` when the user closes the sidenav. It seems there is an event for checking while the menu is being opened with `opening`, but I don't know how to track when the user closes the menu.

Answer (score 34):

For using ionDrag, ionOpen, ionClose in Ionic2 you must add it on the menu itself

for example modify menu in your app.html file by

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" (ionOpen)="menuOpened()" (ionClose)="menuClosed()">
```

After I use "Events" see doc here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/

For detect in my page if the menu was close or open.

Example in my app.ts

```
menuClosed() {
    this.events.publish('menu:closed', '');
}

menuOpened() {
    this.events.publish('menu:opened', '');
}
```

And in my other page

```
events.subscribe('menu:opened', () => {
    // your action here
});

events.subscribe('menu:closed', () => {
    // your action here
});
```

I hope this help

Answer (score 5):

It seems new events have been added to the menu component which solves this problem. I am also using the google maps plugin and it works fine
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/

**ionDrag**

When the menu is being dragged open.

**ionOpen**

When the menu has been opened.

**ionClose**

When the menu has been closed.

Using these output events, in your handlers you can keep a flag for the menu if its open or not :)

Comment: I have the same issues and I found the same events in the doc but i don't find how to subscribe to them. Can you show me ?

Comment: Here is how you use ionClose in your .html file: (ionClose)="methodToExecute()". I was also looking for how to "subscribe" to it, I guess it will help someone ^  ^